# Как победить проблему с высотой блока на IOS9?

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, responsive

Блок не тянется на высоту вьюпорта, на IOS8 этой проблемы нет.
Подскажите пожалуйста как с этим справиться и достичь просто фиксированной верстки
высота правого блока 78vh

```css
.wrapContent {
    overflow: visible!important;
    height: auto!important;
    min-height: 100% ;
    margin: 0 auto -71px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    background: #323742;
}

.header {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 189px;
}

.col-xs-12 {
    float: left;
  }

.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.leftBlock {
    min-height: 78vh;
    float: left;
}

.rightBlock {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #e5e9ec;
    background: #f6f6fa;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapcontent">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <header id="header"></header>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="content clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="flex-container ng-scope">
                <div class="col-xs-8 leftBlock">...</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 rightBlock">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <footer id="footer" class="footer clearfix"></footer>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код основных блоков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно просто убрать

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```